# b String with several inputs (TypeError: %b requires a bytes-like object, or an object that implements __bytes__, not 'str')

Tags: python, string, sockets

I am trying to code a String with several inputs, but this String should be converted into bytes because I am doing a program that connects to a server (using sockets), that uses a protocol which needs to receive messages in bytes.
I am doing the following code:

```
print("Please introduce your username: ")
username = input()
print("Please introduce your password: ")
password = input()
client_socket.send(b"AUTH:%s:%s\n"%(username, password))
```

It gives me the following error:

```
%b requires a bytes-like object, or an object that implements ____bytes____, not 'str'
```

The server should receive the following message:

```
AUTH:username:password
```

with the appropiate username and password in order to log in.

Do you have any idea about how to make this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```py
username = input()
password = input()
data = "AUTH:{}:{}\n".format(username, password)
client_socket.send(data.encode())
```

Explanation:

1. Obtain the data you need
2. Use string [formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to build the string you require<sup>1</sup>.
3. Use the build-int [`encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) method of strings to obtain a byte object<sup>2</sup>.
4. Profit!

---

<sup>1</sup>You can also use [python's f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) or python's [printf-style formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) to build the string you need.

<sup>2</sup> The default encoding is UTF-8, which gives you access to the entire Unicode character set. You can gain more insight about string encoding in the [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html).

Comment: This is the correct approach, although I'd recommend an explicit encoding and an explanation as to why.

Comment: You are right @MadPhysicist, explicitly declaring the encoding is important. If you are sure you are using UTF-8, you can use `...encode(encoding="utf-8")` (which is set by default)